# Child bundle not overriding parent bundle translations

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to override the translations in the default `FOSUserBundle.en.yml`. I have my User bundle as a child of the FOSUserBundle using the `getParent` method and I copied the `FOSUserBundle.en.yml` into the `translations` folder of the child bundle and nothing is being overridden. Can someone help me find out why this is?

I know I have to be missing something because I was able to override the `layout.html.twig` file easily doing the same thing.

I tried using `php app/console cache:clear` and that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the translation file was overriding but the `FOSUserBundle` was *after* the child bundle in the `AppKernel` file. Because of how translations work the `translation` file from the `FOSUserBundle` was being loaded *after* the childs `translation` file, in turn overriding the child.

All I had to do was move the child bundle in the `AppKernel` file *after* the parent. This way it was the last translation file to be loaded.

Here is the documentation page I found this at:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#override-translations

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before as well. Try manually deleting your cache/dev directory. I'm guessing your talking about the dev environment as cache:clear without parameters defaults to dev.

Comment: I manually deleted the directory and it is still not being overridden :(